# Purple line number in Chrome Sources panel

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Why are some line numbers purple in the Sources panel? Are there any offical documentation saying that?

Comment: Should be [modified lines](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/devtools-digest#source_diffs).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I did modify the file in my IDE, not in Chrome.. it's weird that Chrome also detects this..

Comment: That is because you have the filesystem mapped and it detects the git changes.